# User activity monitoring log

Tags: logging, monitoring, user-activity

i need to monitor user's activity i.e mouse and keyboard activities over some period of time and to get the results in log file that provides date and time, and the activity.
Do you know about such tool that doing that or some code in C# that can do it?

Comment: i want to know about keyboard strokes and mouse movements and clicks, that is user activity for me.

Comment: What you seem to be looking for is something similar to a keylogger. Are you looking for an App or tool ? You might want to try blackbox. It is a keylogger app, with datetime and screenshots.

Comment: I'm not interested in the keys pressed, only to know if some key were pressed, and in what time. same with the mouse.
i'll try blackbox.